# How to count letters from print result?

Tags: python, count

I'm trying to compute code to find accuracy score from one-hot MNIST letters data. I want to calculate the accuracy per label in MNIST data because I use the same for precision, recall, and f1 score. `y_true` is dataframe `[88800, 26]`. First, I define true positive, true negative and the others. My code is:

```
for i in y_true:
x=y_true[i]
y=y_pred[i]
    for j in range(len(x)):
       if (x.values[j] == 1) and (y.values[j] == 1):
           print("True Positive", y_pred.columns[i-1])
       elif (x.values[j] == 0) and (y.values[j] == 0):
           print("True Negative", y_pred.columns[i-1])
       elif (x.values[j] == 0) and (y.values[j] == 1):
           print("False Positive", y_pred.columns[i-1])
       else:
           print("False Negative", y_pred.columns[i-1])
```

And the output is:

```
True Positive 1
True Positive 1
True Negative 1
...
True Negative 26
```

Till as much as the rows where 1 and 26 are each label. But, I realize, that I cannot count how much True Positive, True Negative, False Positive and False Negative per label from print result. I dunno have idea how to count it. Is it possible to count it from print result?

Comment: create  count vars and increment inside if stmt

Comment: Before the loop, create four variables named `true_positive`, `true_negative`, etc. and initialize them all to zero.  After each print statement, increment the corresponding variable.

Comment: why don't you just e.g. add the label to a list inside the if statement where you are printing (e.g. `output_list.append("TP")` below `print("True Positive")`). Then you can easily count instances.

Comment: I still cannot get the count of each label and variables. It's not count instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Counter` In your code:

```
from collections import Counter

   c = Counter()


   for j in range(len(x)):
       if (x.values[j] == 1) and (y.values[j] == 1):
           print("True Positive", y_pred.columns[i-1])
           c.update([f'"True Positive" {y_pred.columns[i-1]}'])
       elif (x.values[j] == 0) and (y.values[j] == 0):
           print("True Negative", y_pred.columns[i-1])
           c.update([f'"True Negative" {y_pred.columns[i-1]}'])
       elif (x.values[j] == 0) and (y.values[j] == 1):
           print("False Positive", y_pred.columns[i-1])
           c.update([f'"False Positive" {y_pred.columns[i-1]}'])
       else:
           print("False Negative", y_pred.columns[i-1])
           c.update([f'"False Negative" {y_pred.columns[i-1]}'])
```

After this, the `c` will be your desired output.

For printing the output use this:

```
for k,v in dict(c).items():
    print(k,':',v)
```

Comment: at `c.update([f'"True Positive" {y_pred.columns[i-1]}'])` is it must to all True Positive?

Comment: no it returns `True Negative 1`. with the index. then the counter will automatically count all same outputs.@muthikin

Comment: But you should use `python>=3.6` for this formatting. if you use another version, let me know I will update my answer.

Comment: The output i want is:

`True Positive 1: ?
True Negative 1: ?
False Positive 1: ?
False Negative 1: ?
True Positive 2: ?
True Negative 2: ?`

But, when i run print (c) outside the loop, it just show last index. And when i print (c) inside the loop, it showed as much as the rows @mehrdad

Comment: @muthikin I updated my answer so you can print the desired output.

Comment: It works, but, the result show only False Negative and True Negative for each index. Is it means that True Positive and False Positives all zero? @mehrdad

Comment: @muthikin yes, it means that those strings never added to `c`, so they repeated zero times, it means never.

Comment: the code you gave me yesterday, it works, thank you But, after i try to find the accuracy score value, they didn't work out.

`value=dict(h)
print(value)
acc_score_1=(value['"True Negative" 1'] + value['"True Positive" 1'])/(value['"True Negative" 1'] + value['"True Positive" 1'] + value['"False Negative" 1'] + value['"False Positive" 1'])
print("Accuracy Score 1: ", acc_score_1)`

But, it gives error here: `KeyError: '"True Negative" 1'` why? Eventhough when i `print(value)` everything shows up, but why it gives error when i try to get accuracy score? @mehrdad